# Change User Role in Admin Panel

Tags: meteor, alanning-roles

I'm creating an admin panel where I am able to change the user roles via a select control while using `alanning:roles`. The issue I am having is I am unable to get the user that is associated with each select control. I referenced [this tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/building-a-user-admin) on creating an admin panel with Meteor, but when I call the method to changeRoles, the console returns this error:

**Original Issue: Solved**

```
Error: Missing 'users' param
I20190218-14:59:27.319(-6)?     at Object._updateUserRoles (packages/alanning_roles.js:684:23)
I20190218-14:59:27.319(-6)?     at Object.setUserRoles (packages/alanning_roles.js:250:11)
I20190218-14:59:27.320(-6)?     at MethodInvocation.changeRole (server/main.js:88:13)`
```

***Changed code from:***

```
Template.userHome.events({
    'click #confirmChanges': function (event) {

        let currentRole = $(event.target).find('option:selected').val();
        let userId = $(event.target.id).val();
        console.log(userId);
        if (window.confirm("Change User Roles?")) {
            Meteor.call("changeRole", {
                role: currentRole,
                user: userId
            })
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
})
```

***To this (change in how I set userId value):***

```
Template.userHome.events({
    'change [name="userRole"]': function (event) {

    let currentRole = $(event.target).find('option:selected').val();
    let userId = $(event.target.id);
    console.log(currentRole);
    if (window.confirm("Change User Roles?")) {
        Meteor.call("changeRole", {
            role: currentRole,
            user: userId
        })
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

})

**Now, Roles.setUserRoles() is not working yet parameters have values**
*console.log(options.role) returns the correct value* and

*console.log(options.user) returns:*

```
I20190219-20:37:37.527(-6)? { length: 0,
I20190219-20:37:37.528(-6)?   prevObject: 
I20190219-20:37:37.529(-6)?    { length: 0,
I20190219-20:37:37.529(-6)?      prevObject: 
I20190219-20:37:37.529(-6)?       { length: 0,
I20190219-20:37:37.530(-6)?         prevObject: [Object],
I20190219-20:37:37.530(-6)?         context: [Object],
I20190219-20:37:37.531(-6)?         selector: '3FzfDhZWcGFg6ggTE' },
I20190219-20:37:37.531(-6)?      context: { location: [Object] } },
I20190219-20:37:37.532(-6)?   context: 
I20190219-20:37:37.532(-6)?    { location: 
I20190219-20:37:37.532(-6)?       { href: 'http://localhost:3000/userHome',
I20190219-20:37:37.533(-6)?         ancestorOrigins: {},
I20190219-20:37:37.533(-6)?         origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
I20190219-20:37:37.534(-6)?         protocol: 'http:',
I20190219-20:37:37.534(-6)?         host: 'localhost:3000',
I20190219-20:37:37.534(-6)?         hostname: 'localhost',
I20190219-20:37:37.534(-6)?         port: '3000',
I20190219-20:37:37.535(-6)?         pathname: '/userHome',
I20190219-20:37:37.535(-6)?         search: '',
I20190219-20:37:37.536(-6)?         hash: '' } } }
```

**Client Code:**

```
Template.userHome.events({
    'change [name="userRole"]': function (event) {

        let currentRole = $(event.target).find('option:selected').val();
        let userId = $(event.target.id);
        console.log(currentRole);
        if (window.confirm("Change User Roles?")) {
            Meteor.call("changeRole", {
                role: currentRole,
                user: userId
            })
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
})
```

**Server Code:**

```
Meteor.methods({
  changeRole( options ) {
    console.log("Change User is Being Called");
    try {
      Roles.setUserRoles( options.user, [ options.role ] );
      console.log(options.role)
    } catch( exception ) {
      console.log(exception);
    }
  }
});
```

**UserHome Template**

```
<div class="nav">
    <p class="welcomeUser">Welcome, {{#with userInfo}}{{profile.firstname}} {{profile.lastname}}{{/with}}</p>

    <button id="logout" class="universalButton">Log Out</button>


</div>
<div class="pageContent">



    {{#if userIsAdmin}}
    <div class="adminPanel">
        <table id="userTable">
            <caption>Admin Panel</caption>
            <tr>
                <th class="usertableHead">Username</th>
                <th class="usertableHead">Role</th>
            </tr>
            {{#each users}}
            <tr>
                <td class="usertableData">{{username}}</td>
                <td class="usertableData">
                    <div class="styled-select purple rounded">
                        <select id={{_id}} name="userRole">
                            <option value={{roles}}>{{roles}}</option>
                            <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
        <button id="confirmChanges" class="universalButton">Confirm Changes</button>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to get the `options.user` on the server? Try to console log it and before passing it to `Roles.setUserRoles`.  Also, would be helpful if you can show us the `userHome` template html.

Comment: I updated the way I set the user value which was originally undefined to get the value from event using  let userId = $(event.target.id).val(); and then                  user: userId, but I still am getting undefined for its value @SudheerJami

Comment: Also I did fix the original issue by calling the method on change of the select element, but now I have realized my Roles.setUserRoles() is not working.

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest code. Thanks

Comment: Updated code and issue now is with the event.target.id value returning an object, and thus not being a valid param @SudheerJami

Comment: As a side note - unrelated to your question - you should probably insert a Roles check in your method, otherwise any user can call that method from the JavaScript console and update their role. If you want this to be something only admins can do, check the role of the user calling the method and if they aren't admin, fail the role change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(options.user)` should print the `_id` of the user, not a jQuery object. In your `change [name="userRole"]` event, replace `let userId = $(event.target.id);` with `let userId = event.target.id;`

The better way of assigning and retrieving values is as below:

HTML:

```
...
  <select data-id={{_id}} name="userRole">
       <option value={{roles}}>{{roles}}</option>
       <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
  </select>
...
```

JS:

```
Template.userHome.events({
    'change [name="userRole"]': function (event) {
        let userId = event.target.dataset.id;
        let currentRole = event.target.value;
        console.log(userId, currentRole);
        ...
    }
})
```